# ElasticSearch @query working properly in Kibana but not from java?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Kibana:

GET my_index/topiccollection/_search
{"size":200,"sort":[{"updated_on":{"order":"desc"}}],"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"wildcard":{"team_name":{"value":"*melp*"}}}],"filter":{"term":{"topictype":"0"}},"minimum_should_match":1}}}

Java:

@Query("{"bool":{"should":[{"wildcard":{"team_name":{"value":"?1"}}}],"filter":{"term":{"topictype":"0"}},"minimum_should_match":1}}")

Page getTopicListByKeyword(String userName, String keyword, Pageable page);

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. The wildcard is working fine with lowercase. When i tried to convert my string parameter to lowercase then I got the results appropriately.